# How to replace browser scrollbar arrows with rounded buttons?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to create rounded buttons for the scrollbar arrows. The implicit one looks like

[image]

I need to create one like this:

[image]

I tried to use `background-image` by replacing buttons with `svg` but without success.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement {
    background-image: url("/assets/images/down_arrow.svg");
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {
    background-image: url("/assets/images/up_arrow.svg");
}
```

Any idea ? Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

I made it work like this, maybe you didn't give the scrollbar buttons width and height?

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: url("https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190515/original/pngtree-arrow-icon-in-flat-style-png-image_3548830.jpg");
    background-size: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: The problem is I couldn't make it go wider than the scrollbar, so there's that.